# php mail() keeps returning false. Coding issue or hosting issue

Tags: php, email

I have the following .php file:

```
<?php

$to = "myaddress@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST["from"];
$subject = $_POST["subj"];
$message = $_POST["body"];
$headers = "From: ".$from.
     " X-Mailer: php";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
  header("Location: resume.html");
} else{
   echo("<p>".$to." ".$from." ".$subject." ".$message." ".$headers."</p>");
}

?>
```

Every time it's called upon, it returns false. Any ideas?

Comment: try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see if any other errors show up.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to new headers being "injected" (a bit like SQL injection). Although the potential for damage is small, an attacker could at least add a "Cc" line, so that they can find out your `$to` address

Comment: `mail()` is horrible when debugging. If you end up spinning your wheels trying to find the problem you can temporarily(or permanently) try a mailing library like SwiftMailer. These libraries will give you much better feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Your headers are incorrectly formatted. You must have `\r\n` between them, not a space as you appear to have here.

```
$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n"
          ."X-Mailer: php";
```

Comment: Added the suggested \r\n. No luck. I'll try an alternate route I suppose.

Comment: Oddly enough the mail will go through when I changed the code to '$headers = "From: " + $from."\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";' But this returns a 0 where the from address should be. Is that only because + is not properly formatted?